# Jenkins pipeline, Cucumber test step : Session deleted because of page crash from tab crashed

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, cucumber, docker-swarm

I am facing the issue. When I try to build my Jenkins pipeline, there is one test step which always fails. Note: When I build Docker image on swarm mode, locally it works as expected and there are not any failure tests. I use chrome=56.0.2924.87, chromedriver=2.27.440175, selenium/hub: 3.0.1, os.name: 'Linux'(on Windows ok)

```
 @When("^I want to preview customizations$")
    @DescribedAs("I want to preview customizations")
    public void previewCustomizations(){
        final String idButton="previewCustomization";
        commonDefinition.getBrowsers().execute(browser -> {
            final WebElement webElement = browser.findElement(By.id(idButton))
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new CucumberException(String.format("Unable to find overview button by [%s] id", idButton)));
            webElement.click();
        });
    }


Tests run: 26, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 7, Time elapsed: 0.003 sec <<< FAILURE! - in Scenario: XXXX
I want to preview customizations(Scenario: XXXX)  Time elapsed: 0.003 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: session deleted because of page crash
from tab crashed
  (Session info: chrome=56.0.2924.87)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440175 (9bc1d90b8bfa4dd181fbbf769a5eb5e575574320),platform=Linux 3.10.0-514.21.1.el7.x86_64 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 1.74 seconds
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:48:19 -0700'
System info: host: '', ip: '', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-514.21.1.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_121'


org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: session deleted because of page crash
from tab crashed
  (Session info: chrome=56.0.2924.87)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440175 (9bc1d90b8bfa4dd181fbbf769a5eb5e575574320),platform=Linux 3.10.0-514.21.1.el7.x86_64 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 1.74 seconds
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:48:19 -0700'
System info: host: '', ip: '', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-514.21.1.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.27.440175 (9bc1d90b8bfa4dd181fbbf769a5eb5e575574320), userDataDir=/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.70A1hR}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=56.0.2924.87, platform=LINUX, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=accept}]
Session ID: 1e439001dcab758d5e223feb8215ecc9
Command duration or timeout: 1.90 seconds
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:49:13 -0700'
System info: host: '', ip: '', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-514.6.1.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.27.440175 (9bc1d90b8bfa4dd181fbbf769a5eb5e575574320), userDataDir=/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.70A1hR}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=true, version=56.0.2924.87, platform=LINUX, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, webdriver.remote.sessionid=600786ad-3faa-49a9-b056-09acb1aec681, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=accept}]
Session ID: 600786ad-3faa-49a9-b056-09acb1aec681
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:168)
```

Comment: Please read why a [**`screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea`**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: Did you give Jenkins user executable permissions over your driver binaries inside the containers?

Comment: Yes, I have. I have 3 scenarios but only one of them fails.

Comment: Can you update the question with the code block where the `WebDriverException: unknown error: session deleted` occurs and the relevant error stack trace.